# markup in xsl xml

Tags: html, xml, xslt, architecture

I currently have html markup stored in xsl and xml. This has previously enabled me to render html markup based on variables I pass into the xsl file. The purpose is to serve common page features such as banner, footer based on site variables. As the project got bigger, I find this approach limiting, as I ended up replicating quite bit of the contents within the xml/xsl files to suit the individual needs of each site.

What is the alternative to xsl/xml? Are there currently better otpions? Coming from a programming perspective, I find it very limiting.

Comment: The problem isn't that you are using XSLT but with the way you are using it. It is a good practice not to embed html into XSLT stylesheets, but to have the (x)html in separate files -- I call this the "fill-in-the blanks" design pattern. If your question were more specific, I or other people could provide more specific answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a gazillion web templating frameworks out there.  Here's the [wikipedia entry on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system), which is fairly thorough.

Are you doing the rendering client-side?  There are a pile of [client-side templating options in that article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system#Client-Side_Systems), but the only one I have looked into is [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html), which seems to strike a nice balance of simplicity and functionality.  Actually, Mustache can be run server-side as well.

Good luck!